# How to prevent shrinking content inside drawer menu?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm following this tutorial: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_sidenav.asp to create drawer sidebar menu.

But in my case, I have to add wall of text instead of `<a>` links. Problem is those text grows and shrinks when the drawer opens and closes. https://jsfiddle.net/52qukbow/

```js
function openNav() {
  document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "500px";
}

function closeNav() {
  document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
}

.sidenav {
  height: 100%;
  width: 0;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #111;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  transition: 0.5s;
  padding-top: 60px;
}

.content {
  color: white;
}

.sidenav .closebtn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 25px;
  font-size: 36px;
  margin-left: 50px;
}

@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
  .sidenav {
    padding-top: 15px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
  <div class="content">
    Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas
    sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora
    incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate
    velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?
  </div>
</div>

<h2>Animated Sidenav Example</h2>
<p>Click on the element below to open the side navigation menu.</p>
<span style="font-size:30px;cursor:pointer" onclick="openNav()">&#9776; open</span>
```

How do I prevent the content inside drawer menu grows and shrinks as the drawer opens and closes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend you not to use w3schools if you want to learn things correctly. There are plenty of tutorials that are better than them. If you need references to things I would use MDN instead.

1. Don't use `<a>` if it's not a link, use `<button>` for "action things" that you want to perform stuff.
2. Use classes and toggle them for states instead of js manipulation for things that CAN be done with css.
3. Try to avoid changing properties that will cause re-paints (simple explanation, it is not that great for performance). Width is re-paint. In my example I use translate which is not (it just moves the element).

I use class querySelector instead of onClick. There are a few things with the css that I would change but I just made the changes for the question.

```js
const toggleNavigationActions = document.querySelectorAll('.js-toggle-navigation')

toggleNavigationActions.forEach(function(action) {
  action.addEventListener('click', function() {
    const slideOutNavigation = document.querySelector('#slide-out-navigation')
    slideOutNavigation.classList.toggle('sidenav--is-open')
  })
})
```

```css
body {
  font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
}

.sidenav {
  height: 100%;
  width: 500px;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #111;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  transition: transform 240ms ease-out;
  padding-top: 60px;
  transform: translateX(-500px);
}

.sidenav--is-open {
transition: transform 240ms ease-in;
  transform: translateX(0);
}

.content {
  color: white;
}

.sidenav .closebtn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 25px;
  font-size: 36px;
  margin-left: 50px;
}

@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
  .sidenav {
    padding-top: 15px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="slide-out-navigation" class="sidenav">
  <button class="closebtn js-toggle-navigation">&times;</button>
  <div class="content">
    Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas
    sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora
    incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate
    velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?
  </div>
</div>

<h2>Animated Sidenav Example</h2>
<p>Click on the element below to open the side navigation menu.</p>
<button style="font-size:30px;cursor:pointer" class="js-toggle-navigation">&#9776; open</button>
```